# Trouble with relative / absolute functions import in scikit-image

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm trying to submit a [PR](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/2139) for scikit-image, but I get a Travis-CI [error](https://travis-ci.org/scikit-image/scikit-image/builds/137117004):

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "doc/examples/edges/plot_canny.py", line 22, in <module>
    from skimage import feature
  File "/home/travis/build/scikit-image/scikit-image/skimage/feature/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .peak import peak_local_max
  File "/home/travis/build/scikit-image/scikit-image/skimage/feature/peak.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..filters import rank_order
  File "/home/travis/build/scikit-image/scikit-image/skimage/filters/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ._frangi import frangi_filter, hessian_filter
  File "/home/travis/build/scikit-image/scikit-image/skimage/filters/_frangi.py", line 2, in <module>
    from skimage.feature import hessian_matrix, hessian_matrix_eigvals
ImportError: cannot import name hessian_matrix
```

I suppose that this might be a circular import error, but I don't quite get how to resolve the issue. I've already [included](https://github.com/Hiyorimi/scikit-image/blob/ef0f81173b2f50e6eca293e1c04985cef144399c/skimage/filters/__init__.py#L57) `frangi_filter` and  `hessian_filter` into filter's module `__init__.py`.

I've also tried [relative](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/2139/commits/110c811eb540704ad2108badd0d0d94050a4cea8) import, which [resulted](https://travis-ci.org/scikit-image/scikit-image/builds/137074819) into the same errors.

How can I do a proper import, so the circular import issue can be resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One ugly hack to resolve this would be to move that import inside the function, like

```
def hessian_filter(image, scale=(1, 10), scale_ratio=2, beta1=0.5, beta2=15):
    """
       Blah-blah-blah
    """
    from ..feature import hessian_matrix, hessian_matrix_eigvals
    # function body
```

You might want to create separate "proxy" functions for `hessian_matrix` and `hessian_matrix_eigvals` to not pollute every function with imports.

Comment: Seems like it is the only way to do it.
Thanks, appreciate!